# How do I get the text from a node of a specific preceding sibling

Tags: xpath

If my XML is like this:

```
<sql result="success">
    <row>
        <column>
            <name>USER_ID</name>
            <value>TEST</value>
        </column>
        <column>
            <name>EMAIL_ADDRESS</name>
            <value>xxx@yyyy.com</value>
        </column>
    </row>
</sql>
```

How do I extract just the text of the node retrieved with this XPath:

```
//value[preceding-sibling::name[1][. = 'USER_ID']]
```

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but why not use this XPath to access the value corresponding to USER_ID? `//column[name = 'USER_ID']/value` or at least `//*[name = 'USER_ID']/value`

Comment: Because I don't know XPath!  Thanks!!!  Simpler is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the `/text()` to get the text child of the element:

```
//value[preceding-sibling::name[1][. = 'USER_ID']]/text()
```

Comment: OK... I thought that.. however, I'm applying it in a DataPower extract action, and that isn't working there.  I suspect it has something to do with DataPower, and not the XPath.  Thanks.